# Getting a snapshot of records where an "event" can mean several entries on the same date

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is really frustrating me.

So, I'm making a database recording people joining and leaving our office, as well as changing roles, in order to keep track of headcount. This is succinctly recorded in the following table:

```
EmployeeID | RoleID | FTE | Date
```

FTE is the proportion of full-time hours the role is worth (i.e. 1 is full-time, 0.5 is part-time, etc). Leaving events are recorded as changing the role to 0 (Absent) and FTE to 0. The trouble is, people can have more than one role, which means that the number of hours they actually worked is a composite of all the events for that employee that occur on the same day. So if someone goes from full time on one project to splitting their time between two projects, a ChangeRole event is logged for each.

So I want to know the total headcount on a monthly basis. Essentially the query I would want is "Select all records from this table where, for each EmployeeID, the date is the maximum date below a specified date." From there I can sum the FTE to get the headcount.

Now I can get some of those things in isolation: I can do max(date), I can do criteria:<#dd/mm/yyyy##. But for some reason I can't seem to combine it all to get what I want, and I'm at a point where I've been staring at the problem so long that it doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT Events.*
FROM Events INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EmployeeID, Max(Date) AS LatestDate
    FROM Events
    WHERE Events.Date < [Date entered]
    GROUP BY EmployeeID) AS S
  ON (Events.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) AND (Events.Date = S.LatestDate)
```

Comment: That's just the thing I was after, yes! I fear my frustrations with Access are just beginning (was the SQL View just an afterthought or something?) but this has been very helpful.

Comment: @alphasmart - yes, the SQL View editor is pretty crude! Just to add to the fun, Access is also prone to stripping out any line breaks you've added for readability... On the other hand, for non-trivial things coding the SQL directly is frequently easier than trying to figure out how the visual designer allows doing it, and when needing a sub-query (i.e., an inner SELECT), you have to code the sub-query manually anyway.